# Is it cheating to override default settings when writing functional tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, functional-testing

I'm writing some tests for a rails application to make sure my index action is paginating the results. I didn't want to create 25+ objects for the test (default items per page is 25), so I changed the default_per_page parameter in my test to a much more reasonable (for testing purposes) 2.

Does this violate any best-practice rules I'm not thinking of? It sits right on the line of clever hack and shameful kludge in my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Clearly Define the Test Objective

I think the word "cheating" is a bit misleading, as the tests are for *your* benefit in exercising and maintaining the code. To that end, anything that accomplishes your test objectives isn't really cheating. The real question is, what is your actual objective?

#### Exercise Behavior, Not Implementation

Let's assume that your test objective is to ensure that pagination should split records across pages. Perhaps your test says:

```
it 'should successfully paginate records into 2 pages' do
  # test that pagination creates two pages
end
```

In that case, making the test simpler by reducing fixture/factory setup clarifies the test. You aren't testing that you have 25 records on the first page; you are just testing that pagination splits results into two pages. You have framed the test according to expected behavior, and defined a non-brittle test that provides flexibility in case you paginate differently in the future.

On the other hand, if you rolled your own custom pagination code instead of using a widely-used and battle-tested pagination gem, then you should certainly be testing *all* the boundary conditions, rather than just a single use case of 25 records per page. A single test is certainly inadequate to test all the relevant permutations here, so if that's your actual test objective, you will need to broaden your tests accordingly.